# Unload / Release / Remove React Native View from runtime

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am creating a App that uses React Native in some part, but not all.

I have an instance of `RCTRootView`

Setting it to `nil` and removing it from the superview doesn't seem to release it.

The CPU and RAM stays high, so it seems the React app stills executing on the threads.

How can I stop it?

Thanks :)

Comment: More Info: [Bridge] Deallocating memory when popping ViewController that contains React Native component #1487
 https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1487

Comment: Did you try a autoReleasePool ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create your own RTCBridge separately and release it ( = nil), not only the view.

Comment: I stumbled on this answer, but unfortunately my memory is still climbing every time I create new RCTRootView.  I create my own RCTBridge and my own RCTRootView with it, and stick it inside some UIViewController.  When UIViewController goes away, why do we have to set anything to nil?  Wouldn't the stack just go away?  We are not in pre-ARC days here, what am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

```
RCTBridge * bridge
[bridge invalidate];
bridge = nil;
```

invalidate and nil will clear all modules from jsbundle and it clears RCTRootView instances from memory .
Note bridge is object of RCTBridge.

Comment: I lost a lot of time on this. Thanks!